# Official name of a common type of Bayesian simulation study

Tags: bayesian, simulation, validation, software

There is a kind of simulation study that is commonly used to validate an implementation of a Bayesian model:

- For independent replication $i = 1, ..., n$:

  1. Draw a set of "true" parameters parameters from the joint prior.
  2. Draw a dataset from the likelihood given the parameter draws from (1).
  3. Approximate the full joint posterior distribution, e.g. with MCMC or variational inference.
  4. For each parameter (index $p$) let $c_{ip}$ = 1 if the $100(1 - \alpha)$% posterior interval covers the prior predictive draw from (1). Otherwise, $c_{ip}$ = 0.
- For each parameter $p$, calculate coverage: $C_p = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = i}^n c_{ip}$. If $C_p < 1 - \alpha$, then there are problems in the model or the software.

This technique is super useful in my team's work, and it has caught a lot of errors. **Does anyone know if it has an official name?** I have been searching but have been unable to find it. At first I thought it was called "simulation-based calibration", but what I am describing does (4) above instead of the calibration part.

#### References

- Andrew Gelman, Aki Vehtari, Daniel Simpson, Charles C. Margossian, Bob Carpenter, Yuling Yao, Lauren Kennedy, Jonah Gabry, Paul-Christian Bürkner, & Martin Modrák. (2020). Bayesian Workflow. https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01808
- Cook, Samantha R., Andrew Gelman, and Donald B. Rubin. 2006. “Validation of Software for Bayesian Models Using Posterior Quantiles.” Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics 15 (3): 675–92. http://www.jstor.org/stable/27594203.
- Talts, Sean, Michael Betancourt, Daniel Simpson, Aki Vehtari, and Andrew Gelman. 2020. “Validating Bayesian Inference Algorithms with Simulation-Based Calibration.” http://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06788.

Comment: Have you considered "posterior predictive checks"?

Comment: I often do when feasible, but this particular simulation does not use the posterior predictive distribution (only the marginal posterior of each parameter). “Posterior predictive checks” and “posterior checks” sound a bit too general for this.

Comment: Also, I would like to find the name that is already widely used in the community, rather than try to invent a name myself

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: Whilst I have heard of people investigating the frequentist properties of credible regions, CRs offer no coverage guarantees. And so I can’t see why you’d conclude a bug in software or model if it didn’t have a particular coverage.

Comment: @innisfree I see your point about frequentism. However, it isn't all that different from actual SBC. http://www.jstor.org/stable/27594203 section 2 paragraph 1 explicitly claims their quantile method generalizes what I described, and SBC in https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01808 generalizes further. All 3 approaches take independent draws from the prior predictive distribution and approximate the posterior for each prior predictive draw. And all 3 approaches compare posterior quantiles to prior predictive draws from simulations.

Comment: No. What they describe in Sec. 2, is more like an average coverage. Averaged over the prior. Which agrees with the amount of probability in the CR

Comment: It does not say that CR has correct coverage for every choice of possible parameter.

Comment: Proof of average property: just write the joint as $p(x,D|M) = p(x|D,M) p(D|M)$. This is distribution from which we’re sampling true parameters and data. Then clear that in every simulation, for whatever $D$ you draw, since $p(x|D,M)$ is the posterior, there’s a X% chance you get a draw that lies the X% CR

Comment: Actually, re-reading, I now find your question ambiguous: do you test for correct average coverage? Or correct coverage for each possible true value?

Comment: I calculate coverage as an average over all prior predictive draws. For any individual prior predictive draw on its own, all I calculate is hit or miss. In other words, I was thinking of coverage itself as an average over the prior. (If I understand correctly, the issue you just raised seems like what section 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06788.pdf is talking about.)

Comment: Thinking out loud: if a rank statistic in SBC is itself a kind of coverage, the aggregate does seem to be a kind of "average coverage".

Comment: Just edited the original post to try to be clearer.